# 8GB graphics card upgrade for Mid 2012 Mac Pro

Tags: graphics-cards

I want this card to be able to handle anything I throw at it. I handle multiple file types through the Adobe CC (video, audio, rasterized, vector, and library) simultaneously and have to support 3 monitors. I've already tried the "Sapphire Radeon NITRO R9 390 8GB GDDR5" but I couldn't get it to work without having to jump through hoops I didn't feel confident in jumping through. Any suggestions?

[Here's the specification for the computer](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP652?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US)

Comment: Please describe the hoops you were trying to jump through concerning the R9 390.

Comment: @AdamWykes I stopped researching when I saw the second post on this page: https://www.reddit.com/r/hackintosh/comments/45uo55/r9_390_on_el_capitan/

Comment: That would be because you were trying to use it with Hackintosh, which usually makes for... interesting issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend the **[AMD FirePro W7100 Professional Graphics Card](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1108354-REG/amd_100_505724_firepro_w7100_8gb_gddr5.html)**.

- It supports 4 monitors
- It has 8gb DDR5 vRAM
- Since it is not made by an OEM we can expect it to conform to AMD spec that hackintosh is relying on in order for it to work
- It is rated for less than 150W TDP, so it fits within the 300W envelope your Mac Pro is rated for - you could even have two of them
- Since it is a pro card it is particularly suited to the type of work you are doing and is very stable and well-supported compared to gaming cards like the R9 390
- It is not hideously expensive compared to other, better FirePro cards available
- It is relatively new, so you shouldn't miss out on any newer features like VCE